# Не запускается программа. PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Начал изучать PyQt5, но при запуске pyton выдает ошибку. Удалил старые версии питона и поставил новый(3.8.5), изменил путь интерпретатора, но всё ровно не работает. Как можно это пофиксить?

[image: error]

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Первая программа')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/101157/no-qt-platform-plugin-could-be-initialized

Comment: По пути (путь до python по умолчанию):
C:\Users\(USERNAME)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages есть каталоги "PyQt5", "pyqt5_tools"? С учетом того, если код запускаешь без виртуального окружения.

Comment: да, библиотеки поставлены.